# Python/PySide ImportError

Tags: python, pyside

So I have recently started to learn python and the toolkit PySide but I have ran into a problem which I can't find a solution to, here is the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Callum\workspace\Application\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ui.window import Window
  File "C:\Users\Callum\workspace\Application\ui\window.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ui.menubar import MenuBar
  File "C:\Users\Callum\workspace\Application\ui\menubar.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ui.window import Window
ImportError: cannot import name 'Window'
```

and Here is the code:

main.py:

```
from ui.window import Window

wind = Window()
wind.Create()
```

window.py:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from ui.menubar import MenuBar

class Window:

    title = "Callum"
    minWidth = 980
    minHeight = 640
    app = None
    win = None

    def Create(self):

        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.win = QMainWindow()

        self.win.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.win.setMinimumSize(self.minWidth, self.minHeight)

        mB = MenuBar()
        mB.Create()

        self.win.show()

        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
```

menubar.py:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from ui.window import Window

class MenuBar:

    def Create(self):

        wind = Window()
        menu = wind.menuBar()

        fileMenu = menu.addMenu("File")
        fileMenu.addAction("Exit", exit)
```

Comment: You've got circular imports - you need to shuffle your menubar and window code so they're not trying to import each other.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look carefully at the traceback, you will see that:

1. **main.py** imports `ui.window`

then:

2. **window.py** imports `ui.menubar`

and then:

3. **menubar.py** imports `ui.window`

And now we're into an infinite loop of imports, with `window` importing `menubar` importing `window` importing `menubar` ... etc, etc. Except that of course python prevents this situation from happening by raising an error instead.

However, there are other problems with how the application is structured. In particular, the `Menubar.Create` method creates a new instance of `Window`, adds some menu items to it, and then immediately throws the results away. What you should instead do, is pass an existing instance of `Window` to `Menubar.Create` as an argument, like this:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
# remove the follwing import, which is not needed
# from ui.window import Window

class MenuBar:

    def Create(self, wind):
        # don't create a new instance
        # wind = Window()
        menu = wind.menuBar()

        fileMenu = menu.addMenu("File")
        fileMenu.addAction("Exit", exit)
```

and then in **window.py**, do this:

```
    self.win = QMainWindow()
    ...
    mB = MenuBar()
    mB.Create(self.win)
```